# Unable to add trigger to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc

I am trying to add **SQS** as a trigger to my **Lambda** function running in AWS-VPC but it throws error as :

[image]

```
An error occurred when creating the trigger: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: d34b7525-5c69-4434-a015-112e8e74f447; Proxy: null)
```

> Tried via adding `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` to the policy for
> the role as well via IAM. But no luck!

I am unable to figure where I am making a mistake? Please help me out, if anyone had similar experience in past or knows how to resolve it. Thanks you in advance!

Comment: You need to add access for sqs in you role. The policy that you mentioned can provide access to vpc resources only. SQS is another managed service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please attach managed policy `AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole` in your lambda execution role.
If your lambda function is working with any other aws services, you can try creating custom role and add specific permissions.

In aws if any service want to access any another service you need those specific permission in role.

for more information on lambda permission please check [Managed lambda permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)

Comment: I have these policies : AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole already added.  But doesn't works!

Comment: @Amitkumar maybe you also need to add AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole it worked for me by adding these three roles

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the following actions to the IAM Role attached to your lambda:

- sqs:ReceiveMessage
- sqs:DeleteMessage
- sqs:GetQueueAttributes

Otherwise your lambda will not be able to receive any message from the queue. DeleteMessage action allows to remove a message from queue once its successfully processed. As a resource set the ARN of your SQS queue. Policy should look like this:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "sqs:DeleteMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:region:accountid:queuename",
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

If you're looking for a managed policy, have a look at AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a policy for a lambda role you might have to change account_number to your account no if you need to invoke another lambda form this lambda

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:**eu-west-1**:**account_number:function**:*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```